# NSString length not correct when checked?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a problem with this function :

```
- (bool) test : (NSString *) chaine
{
    NSLog(@"%i",[chaine length]);
    if([chaine length] == 19) NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

I correctly have 19 in my log, but not "Test". So do you know what's wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you posted the exact code you tried to run?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you cast `[chaine length]` to `(int)[chaine length]`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure this is the exact code. chaine is a string I get from a XML file and have to reuse. It contains for example : "A ou B selon profil".
I tried to cast it, it doesn't affect the result. Honestly I've no idea what's wrong, I tried to get the length, to look for hidden chars, nothing seems to be wrong..

Comment: Sorry for suspecting your debugging expertise, but can you just place a breakpoint in above function and make sure 19 is printed by the same NSLog itself. There is no explanation for what you are seeing right now..

Comment: don't you have `return` somewhere inside this method?

Comment: what happens if you use `if([chaine length] == 19L)` ?

Comment: No idea why this question got downvoted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this

```
- (void)testFunction{
NSString * aStrFunc= @"StackOverflow";

NSLog(@"%d",[aStrFunc length]);

NSLog(@"%@",[aStrFunc length]==13?@"test right":@"test not right");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
- (bool) test : (NSString *) chaine
{
    //CGFloat len = (float)[chaine length];
    NSUInteger len = [chaine length];
    NSLog(@"%i", len);
    //if (19.0f == len)
    if (19 == len)
    {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you ever compare float values using "==" ?

Comment: @GoroshkoPavel — your code now is practically the same as from the OP. how is it supposed to be helpful?

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
NSData* data=[chaine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"@s",[data bytes]);//watch the string's bytes possibly you have some unprintable symbols here
if ([data length] == 19) {
NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

Comment: this wont explain, why the [string length] seem to different in to successive lines.